# accessing serialised values in request.session

Tags: django, django-templates

hopefully this is a rather simple question.

If i have the following stored in request.session. Assuming i have multiple items (only one shown here), I'd like to be able to loop over these items and render them as part of a template.

**How can i access the quantity key and value for use within a for loop?**

Here's what I'm trying, however there's no output.

```
{% for item in request.session.bookingContents.items %}
    {{ item.quantity }}
{% endfor %}
```

Variable:

```
'bookingContents'
```

Value:

```
{u'cartID': 51, 
u'items': 
    {u'1': 
        {
        u'quantity': 25}, 
        }
    }
}
```

Further information (updated as this question evolves):

Active template context processors are:

```
'django.core.context_processors.request',
'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
#allauth specific template processors below
'allauth.account.context_processors.account',
'allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount',
'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
```

Comment: How are you rendering your template inside your view ?

Comment: Is your bookingContents.items a list or a dictionnary?

Comment: it's a dictionary since every value has a label associated with it. Will check the view output for this. It's sitting on top of a CMS called wagtail so need to check that render call is being used

Comment: it's a dictionary since every value has a label associated with it. The view is using 
return render(request, 'path/to/template', context)

Comment: bformet's updated method worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add [`django.core.context_processors.request`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) to your [template context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS).

Add this to your settings.py

```
from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS as TCP

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = TCP + (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

Then you can access the session from your templates like this and your code should work:

```
{{ request.session.foo}}
```

**UPDATE:**

Ok  your settings and view is fine, then you could try:

```
{% for key, value in request.session.bookingContents.items.items %}
    {{ value.quantity }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks, but that's already there. Active template context processors are:
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    #allauth specific template tags below
    'allauth.account.context_processors.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

Comment: thanks - your updated method works:
{% for key, value in request.session.bookingContents.items.items %}
    {{ value.quantity }}
{% endfor %}